# Is there any way to improve the maintainability index and cyclomatic complexity of this code snippet?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, while-loop, xmlreader

Okay, so this is the code snippet I have in some places of my application. I need to improve the maintainbility index and cyclomatic complexity for this function:

```
private HotelBookLogEntry ParseService(XmlReader xmlReader, HotelBookLogEntry hotelBookLogEntry)
    {
        while (!xmlReader.EOF)
        {
            if (xmlReader.IsStartElement())
            {
                switch (xmlReader.Name.ToLower())
                {
                    case "datefrom":
                        hotelBookLogEntry.HotelBookCriteria.CheckInDate = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlReader.GetAttribute("date"), "yyyymmdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        xmlReader.Read();
                        break;
                    case "dateto":
                        hotelBookLogEntry.HotelBookCriteria.CheckOutDate = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlReader.GetAttribute("date"), "yyyymmdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                        xmlReader.Read();
                        break;
                    case "currency":
                        hotelBookLogEntry.HotelBookCriteria.RequestedCurrency = xmlReader.GetAttribute("code");
                        xmlReader.Read();
                        break;
                    case "hotelinfo":
                        xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("Code");
                        hotelBookLogEntry.HotelBookCriteria.SupplierHotelId = xmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;
                    case "availableroom":
                        hotelBookLogEntry = ParseAvailableRoom(xmlReader.ReadSubtree(), hotelBookLogEntry);
                        break;
                    case "errorlist":
                        hotelBookLogEntry = GetErrors(xmlReader, hotelBookLogEntry);
                        break;
                    default:
                        xmlReader.Read();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                xmlReader.Read();
            }
        }
        return hotelBookLogEntry;
```

Basically, I have different methods with different parameters and return types, and different set of strings used in the `switch case`, but what's common is the `while loop and the if else conditions`. I need to find a way to make this code 'less complex', especially in terms of the number of conditions and loops used.
I had the idea of moving the switch case to a method and then calling that, but that would still be just OK. 
So, is there any way to improve this code?

EDIT: I have been specifically asked not to use Object-XML serialization, or XMLDoc for that matter, unfortunately

Comment: You can apply polymorphism. Separate derived type with a single method for each case string in switch case. And a factory to create instance of the derived type.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Serialize you source xml to objects and use them to create HotelBookLogEntry.

Answer (score 1):

What you possible could do, even if I don't really know if this performs better or yields better complexity results, is to use a `Dictionary` and define several `Action`s for your cases.
I personally like this solution for scenarios like yours because it is quite nice looking and doesn't mess up your code if you have to add some more cases.

I just created a quick example of what I mean:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var delegates = new Dictionary<char, Action<char>>
        {
            {'e', c => { Console.WriteLine("Found an 'e'"); }},
            {'o', c => { Console.WriteLine("Found an 'o'"); }}
        };

        var s = "Hello World";

        var it = s.GetEnumerator();
        while (it.MoveNext())
        {
            if (delegates.ContainsKey(it.Current))
                delegates[it.Current](it.Current);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```